# How to mock and testing an FTP Connection with Mocha

Tags: testing, mocking, ftp, mocha.js

I am using the FTP library to establish an FTP connection to receive files from a specific location. I need to cover with tests mocha

```
    const client = new Client();
    const connect = {
     host: 'host',
     port: 21,
     user: 'user',
     password: 'password'
   }
   
   client.on('ready', function() {
    client.list(function(err, list) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(list);
     client.end();
    });
  });
  client.connect(connect);
```

Comment: Where does the `Client` come from? Need more details

Comment: const Client = require('ftp')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.